# Moving Email Attachment to another folder in Outlook

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I want to move/copy my Email Attachments to new folder in outlook ;/ and my code doesn't work properly.

```
foreach(Item item in findResults.Items)
        {                
             EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, item.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Attachments));

             if(false)
             {
                 // OTC Marker HTML Body
             }
             else
             {
                 if (email.HasAttachments)
                 {
                     foreach (Attachment attachment in email.Attachments)
                     {
                         EmailMessage emailAttachment = EmailMessage.Bind(service, attachment.Id, new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, ItemSchema.Attachments));

                         ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;
                         itemAttachment.Load();

                         EmailMessage mess = itemAttachment.Item as EmailMessage;
                         moveToTestFolder (mess, @"TestFolder");
                     }
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     //to do
                 }
             }  
           }
```

And my moveToTestFolder method:

```
    private void moveToTestFolder (EmailMessage item, string folderName)
    {
       Folder rootfolder = Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);
       rootfolder.Load();

       var folders = rootfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(20));
       var folderItemToMove = folders.FirstOrDefault(f => f.DisplayName.Equals(folderName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

       item.Move(folderItemToMove.Id);
    }
```

I'am trying to move attachment (if it is an email) to special folder in outlook. Moving the normal message is working now.

Comment: You'll need to explain what "doesn't work properly" means.

Comment: I mean nothing happend ;/

Comment: Did you try to step through your methods with the debugger? If nothing happens I' pretty sure you are catching and swallowing an exception that arises at some point in your code.

Comment: here is a problem, this is a service ;/

Comment: In that case you'll have 2 options: **a)** Add Logging/Tracing to your service to track processing. **b)** Create Unit Tests for your methods. Needless to say that option b) is preferable because it allows you to debug your code while running the test in Visual Studio and will not pollute your code with tracing output calls. As a first emergency again I recommend to ensure that all exceptions will be thrown so you will see errors happening in the Windows Event Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because you can only use the Move and Copy operations to copy an actual Mailbox Item not Attachments (you should be getting an error about and Invalid Id). One workaround for this is to get the MimeContent for the Email Attachment you want to move and then create a New object from that MimeCotent and save it to the folder you want to move the Item to eg

```
        foreach (Attachment Attach in EWSItem.Attachments)
        {
            if (Attach is ItemAttachment)
            {
                PropertySet psProp = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
                psProp.Add(ItemSchema.MimeContent);
                ((ItemAttachment)Attach).Load(psProp);
                if (((ItemAttachment)Attach).Item.MimeContent != null)
                {
                    EmailMessage NewMessage = new EmailMessage(service);
                    NewMessage.MimeContent = ((ItemAttachment)Attach).Item.MimeContent;
                    NewMessage.SetExtendedProperty(new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(3591, MapiPropertyType.Integer), "1");
                    NewMessage.Save(folderItemToMove.Id);
                }
            }
        }
```

You don't get full Fidelity of all the Exchange properties on the Message with this method as only the MimeContent is copied which is generally not a problem with Email but will be an issue for other objects types like Contacts, Tasks etc.

Cheers
Glen